# Explode on new line works with "\n" but not with PHP_EOL. Why?

Tags: php

I have this string

[image]

As you can see, it clearly contains a new line. I want to split that message into an array of 2 messages and I figured I'd use `explode()` in combination with `PHP_EOL`, for multi-OS functionality, but I was left surprised as it did not work.

```
explode(PHP_EOL, $str); // Array( [0] => "Divakat has attacked Gergana, dealing 591 physical damage. ( 2 absorbed )
                        // Gergana has died." )

explode("\n", $str); // Array( [0] => ""Divakat has attacked Gergana, dealing 591 physical damage. ( 2 absorbed )", [1] => "Gergana has died." )
```

I would like to ask, why is the first example not working as I expect it to, and is there any way I can make it work, because I would really not like to have to hardcode the new line character in there. Thank you.

## EDIT:

I forgot to mention, the message has been created on the same machine that this code is currently being tested. There are no OS changes.

Comment: because PHP_EOL is probably \r\n

Comment: You may want to look at [preg_split](http://php.net/preg_split) with something like `preg_split('/[\r\n]+/', $str)` to cover the cross-platform scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PHP_EOL` represents the end-of-line sequence for the platform you are currently on. It does not magically make the end-of-line sequence used inside a string be the same as that of the platform.

For example, this is a string with `\n` (the Unix EOL hardcoded):

```
$str = "Hello\nWorld";
```

If you run this on a Unix system, it will print 2:

```
echo count(explode(PHP_EOL, $str));
```

But on another platform it will print 1 because `$str` contains neither the Windows nor the Mac EOL sequence.

**Update:** It doesn't make any difference *where* the input was created; only *how* it was created. You can easily make a string with Unix EOLs on a Windows system by simply including hardcoded `\n`s in it.

Comment: But I dont understand how may this be the case when all the time I've been working under windows?

Comment: Oh my, now I see. I just took a glance at the piece of code that was used to generate this message and it turns out I have hardcoded `\n` in there, LOL. Silly mistake. Thank you, sir!

Comment: @php_nub_qq: Also, keep in mind that `PHP_EOL` is almost useless in practice. If you are both creating and consuming the string it's useless because you have full freedom in choosing the EOL sequence; it only matters if you are creating and someone else is consuming or the converse, and then only if the other party is only expecting to use the native sequence. A valid example would be when you are writing a text file that should be editable by even the most basic text editor on your platform (Notepad, I 'm looking at you).

Comment: Well I use it basically because I develop under windows, but when the time comes to upload my work of art for the world to see, aka put it on my host, it's going to run on linux. So I use `PHP_EOL` to avoid any possible potential issues I may have, if any. Just to be sure I guess :D

Comment: @php_nub_qq: Please read what I wrote carefully. It's almost certain that by using `PHP_EOL` you are making things worse (or at least less convenient), not better. The world doesn't know that you used `PHP_EOL`. Pretty much all PHP code on GitHub uses `\n` instead of `PHP_EOL` and noone has complained so far.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. But I don't see how `PHP_EOL` could make things worse, having in mind that this text will only be split on `EOL`, it will not be displayed as-is, ever

Comment: @php_nub_qq: In that case it's just less convenient :)